# What factors influence movement speed?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In the original Dark Souls, movement speed was only affected by equip load. In DSII, they introduced a stat called 'Agility' that influences movement speed but also still have equipment load.

How is movement speed calculated in Dark Souls 2?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159736/what-are-the-benefits-of-agility

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to the equipment load breakpoints in previous Souls games, if your equipment load is over 70%, you'll roll with a special "fat roll" animation, which is significantly slower and shorter in range than normal rolls. In contrast, any amount of load below 70% seems to use the "standard" roll animation.

In general, the lower your equipment load is (in terms of percentage), the faster you'll move and roll. The burden effect seems to be based on a continuous scale -- rather than discrete breakpoints like the previous games -- so if you lower your equipment load by 1%, you'll move and roll only a *tiny* bit faster. Similarly, the higher your Agility is, the faster you'll move and roll, on what seems to be a continuous scale.

Comment: So Agility has nothing to do with roll speed? and Equip Load has nothing to do with sprinting/weapon speed?

Comment: As far as I know, both equipment load and Agility affect the speed and distance of your roll. I *think* (non-encumbered) equipment load affects the speed of your walk/run, but the effect was extremely minor (if it exists at all) in the crude stopwatch tests that I did. I don't know if sprinting is treated any differently, but I assumed not.

Comment: I remember playing with over 100% Equip Load last night and still being able to completely sprint, but with almost no roll animation. I had focused on Agility, not Equip Load stats throughout.

Answer (score 0):

In fact everything in Dark Souls II is linked to other influencing factors. Your equip burden (determined by none other than your vitality level) affects your movement speed, sprinting speed and rolling speed. If you seek faster movement & (with emphasis) a heavy armorr, put some points in your Vit.