# How does encumbrance work?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In the previous games encumbrance impacted certain movement based actions, like rolling, and worked on a breakpoint system. However I've heard Dark Souls 2 no longer uses a break point system, and my experience in-game seems to suggests this as well.

How does encumbrance work in Dark Souls 2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What factors influence movement speed?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159795/what-factors-influence-movement-speed) The only part that doesn't overlap is the stamina recovery stuff, so I'm kinda borderline on this.

Comment: Your answer is fantastic, however, so perhaps it'd be good to post it over there too? :D

Comment: @PanicBomb: My answer doesn't completely cover the other question, since agility factors into movement speed as well. Also, there are things encumbrance impacts which don't have anything to do with movement speed, so they're really separate questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I've played around in-game and have discovered that  encumbrance impacts roll speed, roll distance, and movement speed. These findings are supported by [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwSNzUD0lms), which also reveals that stamina recovery is affected by encumbrance as well. I've posted the findings from the video and my in-game testing below.

- [Roll Speed](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=BwSNzUD0lms#t=19)

  - Uses encumbrance breakpoints
  - < 70% fast roll speed
  - > 70% slow roll speed
  - > 120% can't roll
- [Roll Distance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=BwSNzUD0lms#t=30)

  - Doesn’t use encumbrance breakpoints, has an indirect relationship (distance decreases as encumbrance increases)
  - Roll distance decreases as your encumbrance increases
- [Stamina Recovery Rate](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=BwSNzUD0lms#t=61):

  - Doesn’t use encumbrance breakpoints, has an indirect relationship (recovery rate decreases as encumbrance increases)
  - Stamina recovery rate is cut in half at 105.8% encumbrance (compared to 0%)
  - With 132 stamina recovery rate was:
  - 2.3s at 0%
  - 3.1s at 56.2%
  - 4.0s at 85%
  - 4.6s at 105.8%
- [Movement Speed](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=BwSNzUD0lms#t=95):

  - Uses breakpoints
  - > 100% walking and sprinting is slower
  - > 120% walking speed further decreases and can no longer sprint