# No description on equipment stats

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have some idea of the stat icons and what they mean like poison resistance etc. But for everything else it's a complete guess. No text, and so far after searching online, nothing posted on it. Anyone have a link or a breakdown of the stat icons actually are on the equipment status menu of the game?

Comment: What you raised is a genuine issue for people who focus on stats and what they do; however, I don't think anyone has yet worked out the exact function of each stat. There have been similar but more specific questions on this issue already on arqade, e.g., http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159795/what-factors-influence-movement-speed

Comment: Since this is a build heavy game I can't imagine why the developers didn't include some form of textual information on each of the stats and how they effect mechanics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you didn't know, you can press Select (on PS3) or Back (on Xbox 360) to bring up a cursor that you can move around the screen to see a name and short explanation for every icon, on almost every menu and status screen that uses such icons.

Example:

[image: DS2 icon help popup screenshot]

If you're looking for a detailed breakdown of the actual math behind each stat, then:

1. That information isn't in the game, in general; and
2. You'd probably be better off making dedicated questions for each major stat group that you're concerned about, because there are simply too many different stats in the game to be reasonably addressed within the scope of a single question.

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question or I misunderstood what you're asking, drop a comment and I'll update it.

Comment: For PC it's `T`, though there's another screen that you can pull up on items by pressing `E`.